# How to set params in my own struts2 tag?

Tags: struts2, tags

We all knows how to use  **s:action**  tag:

```
<s:action name="actionA" namespace="/namespaceA">
   <s:param name="param" value="123"/>
</s:action>
```

now I want to write my own tag, extends from ActionTag, and I give a variable named 'url' to determine an action on my jsp pager:

```
<mytab:action url="/namespaceA/actionA.action?param=123"/>
```

Here are the Java Code:

```
public class ResultTag extends ActionTag {
private String url;//链接

protected void populateParams() {
    super.populateParams();
    ActionComponent action = (ActionComponent) this.component;
    action.setNamespace(getNamespace(url));
    action.setExecuteResult(true);
    action.setName(getActionName(url));
}//other methods}
```

now I don't know where to set my parameters (param=123) on my java code, can anybody tell me how to do?thanks a lot!

Comment: You don't need to set parameter, it's already included.

Comment: No, It didn't work. It calls the correct action without any parameter(param didn't set the value 123), so I want to know how to set the value.

Comment: Why do you want to write your own tag? In general it is not very good approach.

Comment: There has several url in the database, and the requiremnet is to show the result in one page. I don't want to change the database structure, and I don't want to use iframe, so I choose to use struts2 tag.

Comment: How did you parse parameters from the url?

Comment: I want to separate them by using String.split and String.indexOf, do you have good idea?

Comment: Well I got the solution. There's a property call parameter in ActionComponent class, we should only put our parameters into the parameter map:action.getParameters().put('param','123');

Comment: Well, you can post this as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Could you please tell me where can I mark this question?